# How to slowly FadeOut an image ON LOAD using jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I want to have an image fade out slowly on load. Idea is that my name, which you click to enter my site, stays briefly on my homepage, like a visual echo from my intro page.

I'm sure its a snitch, but I'm new to coding and so I am struggling.

I've gleaned that I need to have css visibility:hidden; (not sure if I need to put this in the jquery or in the actual css, or both) as I want the other elements on my page not to jump when image fully dissappears.

NB have substituted image for text in the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cress/BdHmG/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#namefade').fadeOut(5000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BdHmG/7/

Comment: Sweet, but it's the fade I'm after :) Thank you

Comment: just change it to $('#namefade').fadeOut(5000);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#namefade').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).css({visibility: 'hidden', opacity: 0})});
});
```

Changes from what you had:

- use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`
- fadeout before altering css
- alter css in the callback at the end of the animation, not right away

The `.fadeOut()` function takes an optional second parameter, which if defined and is a function will be called in the context of every item that has completed fading out. This is true for all of jQuery's animation functions.

Comment: Thank you! Am just getting my head around the techno-lingo so not 100% understanding how it works. I have the $(document).ready() at the beginning of  my jquery file, (which is one file for all of my sites jquery~ of course aside from plugin files and the library one). I thought the function .load meant for the jquery to work on load. Are you saying its overkill?

Comment: I will try what you suggested

Comment: jQuery will call the function you define in `$(document).ready()` in response to it detecting that the DOM has fully loaded and is ready for interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/BdHmG/4/

I'm wrapping my content that is fading out inside of a div. I'm then setting the height of that div to the height of whatever your image size would be.

Just so you know:

- `visibility:hidden` will hide the element but keep its shape
- `display:none` will hide the element and collapse its shape

Comment: Wow yes! Seth, thankyou so much! Fades a treat, but other elements are jumping. I am still unsure where I put the visibility hidden or display none thingummies though, sorry!

Comment: Still got text jumping and now I realise, my intro page image (my name gif) is out of sync with my home page fade out one. Poss to do with the containing div? the intro page has no containing div, as i want my name image to be relative at all times, in the middle, in relation to browswer window resizing).

Comment: sorted the image sinc. issue with z-index setting. Now have another question, so will repost.