# make image appear ONCE on first page load, but not on subsequent loads

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Am trying to have an image visually echo through from intro page to homepage~which I have sorted, (see other question [How to slowly FadeOut an image ON LOAD using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8703957/1114583) ), but now realise that I have created an irritating effect as the image loads and fades each time the homepage link is clicked.

My question is, how can I have the image load only once, from the intro page?

The visual effect is this...

By clicking my name (link) on the intro page, you get to the homepage, where there is a copy of the name link, which appears briefly, (has the same co-ordinates & with jquery fadeOut applied).

Comment: Couldn't you just set a cookie on your first visit and only show the image if the cookie was not set?

Comment: Ah, cheers. I knew there was a way to do it, but I didnt know what it was called or even how how to do it. Can you assist with info or a link please?

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can use this cookie plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie .  This website also provides a good tutorial: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Cookies

You can easily keep track of whether it is the first time a user is visiting your site by using cookies. Since you are already using jQuery, you can use the jQuery cookie plugin (available at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). In order to keep track of whether to fade in the image or not, you can use this code snippet:

```
if ($.cookie('hasVisited')) {
  // Don't fade the image in...
} else {
  $.cookie('hasVisitied', 'true');
  // Fade image in...
}
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the user accepts cookies. If your want the image to always fade in for users that do not have cookies enabled client side, then that code snippet will work fine.  Otherwise, have a look into [this post](http://blog.nickburwell.com/2009/05/check-if-cookies-are-enabled-on-client.html) on how to detect if cookies are enabled client side; and if they aren't, don't have the image fade in.

### Option 2: URL Parameters

If you find that the demographic of your site has a majority of users that do not enable cookies client side, then you can use URL parameters to designate whether to fade the image or not.

Say for example your home page is at `/index`, then the links in your main menu would link back with `/index?nofade=true`.  Then, in the index page, you can test whether or not the parameter exists using jQuery [as demonstrated in this blog post](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html).

Comment: Thanks so much Ivan, plenty of info. Thing is, I dont want the image to appear at all on the homepage on subsequent views. Is that possible? I will try the /index?nofade=true thing first, as some folk still dont enable cookies. If I cant do that, then I'll go the cookies route. I'm new to coding, so am uncertain how to write/enclose the 'no fade true, css or jquery? (Sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

As @Ivan, explained you need to keep track of if an event happened (ie, did a user visit previously?).

Most commonly this is done using a cookie, and some simple code like:

```
if( $.cookie('visited') ){
// do or don't do something
}
```

You can grab the cookie plugin here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to track your users so that you can determine whether the user has already encountered the image effect.

Your only realistic way of doing this is with **cookies** or with [**client side storage**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/).

Have a research around these topics and once you understand you'll be able to apply either here, but as already mentioned such stuff is trivial to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a jsfiddle that has an example of how you could do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jebx8/

This uses the cookie plugin from here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($.cookie("firsttime") != 1)
    {
        $.cookie("firsttime", "1");
        $('#firstonly').text('Show this first time only');
    }
 });
```